# Ajax#updateColumn() doesn't update cell

Tags: jsf, datatable, omnifaces

I've added OmniFaces to my Primefaces application primarily for being able to update a single row of a dataTable. I'm calling `Ajax.updateColumn(dataTable, 1)` on push event, but nothing gets updated. Eg. one of my cells is like this

```
<p:column style="width:40px;text-align: center;"
    toggleable="false" styleClass="smallPadding unmarkable">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:commandLink styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-car"
            style="display: inline-flex;" id="carIcon" />
    </f:facet>
    <p:tooltip for="carIcon" value="Anzahl freie Fahrzeuge" />
    <h:outputText
        value="#{editLoad.getAmountOfUnusedOrderPositions(order)}" />
    <h:outputText value="/#{order.orderPositions.size()}" />
</p:column>
```

I've debugged and #{editLoad.getAmountOfUnusedOrderPositions(order))} returns 0, but the wrong value (8) is displayed after the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the `Ajax#updateColumn()` javadoc](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/1.8/org/omnifaces/util/Ajax.html#updateColumn(javax.faces.component.UIData,%20int)):

> `public static void updateColumn(UIData table, int index)`
>
> ...
>
> Note that the to-be-updated direct child of `UIColumn` must be a fullworthy JSF UI component which renders a concrete HTML element to the output, so that JS/ajax can update it. So if you have due to design restrictions for example a `<h:panelGroup rendered="...">` without an ID, then you should give it an ID. This way it will render a `<span id="...">` which is updateable by JS/ajax.

Your `<h:outputText>` of interest doesn't have a `id`. Give it one.

```
<h:outputText id="amountOfUnusedOrderPositions"
    value="#{editLoad.getAmountOfUnusedOrderPositions(order)}" />
```